# MsDeploy TextFile provider

Tags: manifest, msdeploy, provider

We are using MsDeploy with Manifest provider, and declareParamFile and setParamFiles.
We would like to replace the string below in a packaged 'runDeploy.cmd' file:
`'SET SrvrName=Dev-ServerName'` (w/o the quotes) .
SO the DeclareParam.xml file has param entry as below

```
<parameter name="DbServer" defaultValue="Prod-Server" >
    <parameterEntry kind="textFile" scope="runDeploy\.cmd$" match="Dev-ServerName" />
</parameter>
```

However, the error that we get is 
Parameter entry 'DbServer/2' could not be applied to 'C:\Src\bld\runDeploy.cmd'. Deployment will continue with the original data. Details:
No matches were found for the search string 'Dev-ServerName' (type 'TextFile')."
Not sure what is the issue with the plain text here. I have also tried various regex but did not work. Any hints what is wrong?

Thanks
Yatin

Comment: Is the runDeploy.cmd file part of your source or a generated file?  If generated when is it generated?

Comment: The rundeploy.cmd file is part of the contentprovider.
Its part of the package, and is being deployed on the destination.

Just for testing I tried to change the match to ServerName (instead of Dev-ServerName), the string got replaced. It's the hyphen that is causing the issue. I do not see a need to escape it with a '\' for regex matching. But even if I did (that would make it Dev\-ServerName), it did not work.

Comment: The MsDeploy version is 7.1.1955.0 .

Comment: I wondered if the hyphen might be the issue.  Try using regex "Dev.ServerName"

Comment: That worked.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hyphen in the match Regex expression may be causing an issue.  Try the following match Regex instead:

```
Dev.ServerName
```

The period represents any character and should match the hyphen.